# How do I select the first column of the array based on the drop down selection?

Tags: javascript, arrays

ok the line that I THINK is messing me up is line 23

```
        tag.innerHTML = maps[this.value][1];
```

But I keep getting
"SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property '1': object is null or undefined " In IE JS console. 
It doesnt display ANYTHING

I also tried

```
        tag.innerHTML = maps[0][1];
```

But all that does is select the first row in the array and then displays the second column in the array regardless of selection.

I want it to select the second column of the row that the user selects. Any help?  here is the full code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
window.onload=function(){
    var maps = new Array();
        maps[0] = ["Text A1", "Text A2", "Text A3"];
        maps[1] = ["Text B1", "Text B2", "Text B3"];
        maps[2] = ["Text C1", "Text C2", "Text C3"];
        maps[3] = ["Text D1", "Text D2", "Text D3"];
        maps[4] = ["Text E1", "Text E2", "Text E3"];
        maps[5] = ["Text F1", "Text F2", "Text F3"];
    var map = document.getElementById("complaintType");
    for (i = 0; i < maps.length; i++) {
        var Entry = document.createElement("option");
        Entry.text = maps[i][0];
        map.add(Entry, null);
    }
    var tag = document.getElementById('tag');
    map.onchange = function () {
        tag.innerHTML = maps[0][0];
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
    <select name="complaintType" id="complaintType">
    <option>Select One</option>
    </select>
</form>
<div id="tag"></div>
<a href="#" >Link</a> | <a href="#">Link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You never set a value for your `option` tags - what do you expect `this.value` to be? Also, you may want to edit your sample code - the `maps[this.value][1]` part is missing, instead you have `maps[0][0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing to this:

```
map.onchange = function () {
    var tag = document.getElementById('tag');
    if(map.selectedIndex != 0)
    {
        tag.innerHTML = maps[map.selectedIndex - 1][1];
    }
    else
    {
        tag.innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: PERFECT THIS IS EXACTLY WHAT I WANTED! I cant upvote yet though :(

Comment: Can I ask you to explain that to me though? I see what you wrote but I dont know WHY it works. You dont have to though

Comment: @RonnelAlfred map is your select which you can get the `selectedIndex` property of your select.  This almost directly maps to your array except you have a place holder for your first element `Select One` at index 0.  So if you select `Text A1` then that is actually `selectedIndex = 1` of your select but index 0 of your maps array.  So you should take the `selectedIndex` of your select and subtract 1 to get the index (row) of your array.  If you are at `selectedIndex = 0` then you should just display "" because maps[-1][1] would throw an error.

Comment: @RonnelAlfred I hope the above explanation helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you set each entry's `value` to `i` in the loop, you'll get what I *believe* you're looking for:

```js
var maps = [
  ["Text A1", "Text A2", "Text A3"],
  ["Text B1", "Text B2", "Text B3"],
  ["Text C1", "Text C2", "Text C3"],
  ["Text D1", "Text D2", "Text D3"],
  ["Text E1", "Text E2", "Text E3"],
  ["Text F1", "Text F2", "Text F3"]
];

var map = document.getElementById("complaintType");

for (i = 0; i < maps.length; i++) {
  var Entry = document.createElement("option");
  Entry.text = maps[i][0];
  Entry.value = i;
  map.add(Entry, null);
}

var tag = document.getElementById('tag');
map.onchange = function() {
  tag.innerHTML = maps[this.value][1];
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select name="complaintType" id="complaintType">
    <option>Select One</option>
  </select>
</form>
<div id="tag"></div>
<a href="#">Link</a> | <a href="#">Link</a>
```